# How to switch the statusBarStyle with the new syntax to remove deprecated warnings?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, ios15

how am I supposed to change this piece of code?
The current solutions for this problem either cover older iOS versions
or are unanswered.
This is the line:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

And I get those warnings:

```
'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.
'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead
```

The code works, but would be nice to do not have those warnings popping up

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove the warning you can use:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *)
```

This function works for me:

```
func setStatusBar() {
        if #available(iOS 13, *)
        {
            let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                    .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
                    .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                    .first?.windows
                    .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
            let statusBar = UIView(frame: (keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame) ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: statubarHeight))
            statusBar.backgroundColor = .white
            keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
        } else {
            let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
            if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
                statusBar.backgroundColor = .white
            }
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        }
    }
```

and you can use for all pages of app in "**General**" settings:

[image]

and in "**info.plist**"

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can create a hosting controller by inheriting UIHostingController and then change the statusBarStyle like this:

```
class HostingController<ContentView>: UIHostingController<ContentView> where ContentView: View {

  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return .lightContent
  }
}
```

And then you can set this hosting controller as your window root view controller in Scene Delegate like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let contentView = YOUR_VIEW

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = HostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for you and as of now I believe the only way is using HostingController.

Comment: No UI Hosting View Controller I want that one line to have no warnings not change the logic

Answer (score -2):

You can override this property in your view controller :

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Plus you can get the value of statusBarStyle like this:

```
    let style = SceneDelegate.shared?.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarStyle
```

but this is only get only property. In order to change the status bar style you can use the above code by overriding the ViewController property.

In case you want to change the status bar style of whole app then you can use info.plist like this:
Add "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" key and set its value to "false"

And then add "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent" key and set its value to "UIStatusBarStyle".

Comment: I am doing this in SwiftUI so how can I use the override part there without using a UIHostingViewController ?

Comment: You didn't mention swiftUI in your question.

Comment: I want the warnings on that line to go away without changing the logic. That's is why I posted that line